# How can I avoid recursion during saving of django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model `Entry`

Now whenever `Entry` is created for any date. Then before saving I need to make check and add more entries, for example e.g.

`Entry 1 - red`

Now suppose if any `entry.color = red` Then I also need to make two more entries like

```
Entry 2 - red2
Entry 3 - red3
```

Now I have put this in pre_save signal

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Entry)
def new_entries(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
     pass
```

Now my problem is this ends in infinite recursion as those new entries which I want to save also send pre_save signal and this loop never finishes.

Where do put this logic so that recursion does not occur?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ Basically its   i need to split the entry if new entry is overlapping in time with previous one.

Comment: Do you need to create the new entries in the same model and is it necessary to create them before creating a new record of that model? Please provide more details

Comment: @chaos yes its same model . i need to create entry , i can be afterwards as well

Comment: then create the entry and send an additional parameter that would say if you have dependencies. If you have dependencies create them if not break. For the dependencies you do not send that parameter. That is if I understand correctly your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would solve it with an additional argument to save, as opposed to attaching to pre_save:

```
import django.db.models
class Entry(models.Model):
    color=models.CharField(max_length="50")
    def save(self,create_children=True,**kwargs):
        if create_children and not self.pk:
            result = super(Entry,self).save(**kwargs)
            Entry(color=self.color).save(create_children=False)
            Entry(color=self.color).save(create_children=False)
        else:
            result = super(Entry,self).save(**kwargs)
        return result
```

You want to make sure you call `super(Entry,self).save(**kwargs)` before you actually construct the children, otherwise you will clutter the database with models when super() raises an `IntegrityError`

Comment: as i am using django rest serializer to save, do i need to return something in the end of save?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have 2 separate models for this. Your 'parent' `Entry` could be a subclass of the main `Entry` model so that only IT creates new child Entries.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    pass
    # whatever you need here

class ParentEntry(Entry):

    @receiver(pre_save, sender=ParentEntry)
    def new_entries(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

The reason for adding another model is that these models actually do 2 different things, 1 creates more when creating, 1 does not. For clarity, I would prevent situations where 1 model's constructor can do 2 separate things.

Comment: If it's only about adding behaviour, then you may want to consider a `Proxy` model instead - but I don't know for sure how they interact with signals...

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
class Entry(model.Model):

   def save(self, color, create_more=True, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.pk is None:  # this is a new Entry              
           if create_more:
               new_color = '%s2' % color
               Entry(color=new_color, create_more=False).save()

       super(Entry, self).save(...)
```

tho I suspect there is a better way, but I can't say without knowing more details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Careful with what is passed to save. This implementation would require the instantiation to be called like: `Entry(color="blue").save("blue")` , see my answer to see how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

In post_save singal in django for avoiding recursion 'if created' check is required

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
@receiver(post_save, sender=DemoModel)
def _post_save_receiver(sender,instance,created, **kwargs):
if created:            
    print('hi..')
    instance.save()
```